# How to use mappedBy correctly in one to many relation

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm, hibernate-mapping, grails-domain-class

I am new to grails. I have a problem with one to many relation with my two classes. I have two classes `Person` and `Child` as follows

```
class Child
      {
         String name
         String grade
         Person father
         Person mother
         Person guide

      }
```

and Person class looks like

```
         class Person
            {
              String name
              hasMany[child: Child]
            }
```

How do I use `mappedBy` here correctly 
I have looked [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#oneToMany) . The example given in that link shows `mappedBy` when the many side has two properties of parent class. how do I use here `mappedBy` correctly? What difference does it make in the database level? Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
class Person {
   static hasMany = [childs: Child]
   static mappedBy = [childs:'father'] //or whichever parent you want to use 
}
```

As you have only one collection in Person domain, you can map it to just one parent. If you want to map childs for all three parents, you will need three collections in the Person

Comment: Thanks.. it works.. But could you please explain how does it work? what change does GORM make when use this mappedBy? I can't get its concept properly..

Comment: Here in your child class you have multiple fields of type Person, so grails cont decide which person object the collection of childs should be associated to, hence you need to specify mappedBy

Comment: what change will happen if I use `static mappedBy = [childs : 'mother']`  or  `static mappedBy = [childs : 'guide']` ?